# WP7 transition between Canvas's in a Grid

Tags: windows-phone-7, transition

I have two canvas's in a Grid, full scene "images" that I want to transition, I wonder how I would go about transitioning between these two Canvas controls.

Programatically I add the first canvas to the grid, then I add the second canvas to the grid, and remove the first, what I really want to do is transition between them.

Any suggestions on how I might achieve this programatically?

Thanks.

**Edit: I have implemented this method, but am having problems, anyone able to tell me if I'm using it wrong?**

```
     private void doTransitionIn(Canvas slide)
    {
        SlideTransition slideLeft = new SlideTransition();
        slideLeft.Mode = SlideTransitionMode.SlideDownFadeIn;

        ITransition transition = slideLeft.GetTransition(slide);

        transition.Completed += delegate { transition.Stop(); }; transition.Begin();
    }

    private void doTransitionOut(Canvas slide)
    {
        SlideTransition slideLeft = new SlideTransition();
        slideLeft.Mode = SlideTransitionMode.SlideDownFadeOut;

        ITransition transition = slideLeft.GetTransition(slide);
        transition.Completed += delegate { transition.Stop(); }; transition.Begin();
    }
```

And here is how I use it:

```
            SceneGrid.Children.Add(nextCanvas);
            doTransitionIn(nextCanvas);
            doTransitionOut(currentCanvas);
            SceneGrid.Children.Remove(currentCanvas);
```

The problem with this is that the animation only seems to start from part way down the screen, as in, i only see it slide the last 20 or so pixels, it doesn't slide all the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by "transition" I'd look at creating a StoryBoard to animate the hiding/showing of each canvas.

Comment: Storyboard worked for me, I tried TransitionContentControl, but it seemed to have no timing and was happening instantly, makinga mess of the effect.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the `TransitioningContentControl` which is part of the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/). To use this control, make your first `Canvas` the `Content` of this control. To transition, simply change the `Content` to your next `Canvas` and the `TransitioningContentControl` does the rest!

There are a number of blog posts that provide tutorials for this control:

http://blogs.academicclub.org/uidev/2010/06/12/transitioning-content-in-silverlight/

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like a suitable solution, however, the web-based silverlight example doesn't help me much and I can't seem to find anything suitable. Is it possible I could get an example?

Comment: WP7 Silverlight has exactly the same control as the Web-based Silverlight. See: http://wildermuth.com/2010/07/16/Bring_Back_Page_Transitions_to_the_Windows_Phone_List_Application_Template

Comment: I'v seen this blog post too, he's embedded it all. THeyre all using the layout root or the page itself which isn't really helping me to understand how this works. I would love to see an example code applying the template/transitionconstrol/style etc for a Canvas/Grid(whichever I@m supposed to perform it on).